# Google apps script authorize script from html file not working

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I am trying to make a Google Apps Script web app. My goal is to show the user an HTML file and have the HTML file send some data back to the script so that it can modify a Google Document. I have the .gs file with the following code:

```
function doGet() {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index").evaluate();
  html.setTitle("Test");
  return html; 
}

function test(url, text) {  
    DocumentApp.openByUrl(url).getBody().doSomethingHere
}
```

I also have the following html file (index.html):

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta name="google-signin-scope" content="profile email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request">
    <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="123456789012-someidhere.apps.googleusercontent.com">
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" async defer></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
    <script>
        function getValue() {
            var text = document.getElementById("text").value;
            var url = document.getElementById("url").value;
            google.script.run.test(url, text);
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="g-signin2" id="signin-button" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-theme="dark"></div>
    <div id="status"></div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <style>
        #signin-button,
        #status {
            float: left;
            display: inline-block;
            padding-left: 5px;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function onSignIn(googleUser) {
            // Useful data for your client-side scripts:
            var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Signed in as ' + profile.getName() + ' (' + profile.getEmail() + ')';

            // The ID token you need to pass to your backend:
            var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
            console.log("ID Token: " + id_token);
        };
    </script>
    <input type="text" id="url" placeholder="Document URL" style="width: 100%;" />
    <BR>
    <input type="text" id="text" />
    <input type="button" value="OK" onclick="getValue();" />
</body>

</html>
```

However, when I enter values and press 'OK', I get an error logged to the console:

*Uncaught Error: Action not allowed
 at test (Code:9) (My Test Script)*

I have seen some suggestions to make sure that the user goes to the script and authorizes it. I do not want to do this. Is there a way to do this with the OAuth 2.0 sign in button so I don't have to have the user go to the script itself? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What does `doSomethingHere`?

Comment: You may refer with this related [thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/Je4PK9lZdyo;context-place=topicsearchin/docs/category$3Achrome%7Csort:relevance%7Cspell:false). There may be some method you're using that has become either unstable or for some reason disallowed in your context. One workaround given is by duplicating the spreadsheet (also works with duplication the script file).

Comment: @Ruben doSomethingHere modifies the background color of a google document